# SQL Random Sample based on minimums for two groupings

Tags: sql, netezza

I have a data set of alerts that are worked by employees. Each alert comes from a specific scenario as well. I have been asked to provide a random sample of 60 alerts from the total population, however the sample must include the following:

1. Sample must contain all scenarios in the population. For instance, if there were 1000 alerts last month, and of those 1000 alerts, there were 15 scenarios that comprised them, I would want to make sure that at least 1 of every scenario was in my 60 count QA sample.
2. The customer wants to make sure that the 60 count QA sample also contains at most 5 alerts per employee, or 100%, whichever is less. For instance, if an employee worked 4 or less alerts, we want all of them in the sample, regardless of what scenarios they were. If they had 5 or more, we just need to get 5 back.

So the sampling is two fold - I need to make sure we get 60 random samples covering all scenarios, but make sure we get the 5 max or 100% of each employee's worked alerts.

The data would look something like:

```
Alert_ID      Scenario      Employee_Name      Etc....
00001         A             John Smith         ....
00002         A             John Smith         ....
00003         B             Jane Doe           ....
00004         C             John Smith         ....
```

I can't post a data set for certain reasons, but the data set is on the order of ~20,000 alerts per month, so I pull those 20k, and from there I need to sample from that population per the above. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

By the way, I am using IBM Netezza and Aginity as an IDE fro this development. Thanks!

Comment: How can you choose 60 alerts and cover 230 scenarios?  I'm confused.

Comment: I need to choose 60 alerts out of the total population of around 20k, but, I need to make sure that sample convers all scenarios and employees. 230 was a bad example, let's say we only had 15 scenarios. I'll edit my post.